# ASP .NET CORE Unable to resolve service for type Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, swagger

This is the interface for Application class

```
public interface IApplicationService
{
    IDataResult<IList<Application>> GetList(Expression<Func<Application, bool>> filter = null, string[]? includes = null);
    IDataResult<Application> GetById(Expression<Func<Application, bool>> filter = null, string[]? includes = null);
    IResult Add(Application entity);
    IResult Update(Application entity);
    IResult Delete(Application entity);
}
```

This is the service class for Application

```
internal class ApplicationService : IApplicationService
{
    private readonly IApplicationDAL applicationDal;

    public ApplicationService(IApplicationDAL applicationDAL)
    {
        applicationDal = applicationDAL;
    }
```

And this class is for the API request

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ApplicationAPIController : ControllerBase
{
    readonly IApplicationService applicationservice;
    readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public ApplicationAPIController(IApplicationService applicationService, IMapper mapper)
    {
        applicationservice = applicationService;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
```

This is my Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
//builder.Services.AddScoped<IApplicationService, ApplicationService>();
//builder.Services.AddScoped<IEventService, EventService>();
//builder.Services.AddScoped<IParticipantService, ParticipantService>();
//builder.Services.AddScoped<IUniversityService, UniversityService>();
//builder.Services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddMvc();

var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger(options =>
    {
        options.SerializeAsV2 = true;
    });
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And last one, this is my Data Access Layer class for Application

```
public interface IApplicationDAL : IEntityRepository<Application>
{
}
```

This picture is about my error message, i tried to change class access but i didn't work out. I dont know where did I make wrong.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Business.Abstract.IApplicationService' while attempting to activate 'ZirveProjesi.Controllers.API.ApplicationAPIController'.
```

at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
at lambda_method3(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()

Comment: You've got `//builder.Services.AddScoped<IApplicationService, ApplicationService>();` commented out so the service isn't being injected by DI currently hence the error

Comment: Post the error/exception text as *text* in the question itself. Images can't be googled, copied, compiled or tested. Although in this case the error is pretty clear - the `IApplicationService` service wasn't registered

Comment: I tried to register IApplicationService but ApplicationService is internal class, it does not work out. That's why I did those comment

Comment: Why you are making it internal? Are all of them in the same project with same namespace?